# Handling UI components in another thread

Tags: java, android, multithreading

I want to change few components in another thread. I did it, but I don't know is it good enough (or too bad). This is how I do:

```
public class FullMapFragment extends Fragment {    

    private AlertDialog alertDialog; //volatile?
    ...
```

Runnable class for handler:

```
public class ShowAlertDialog implements Runnable{

    private AlertDialog alertDialog;

    public  ShowAlertDialog (AlertDialog alertDialog)
    {
        this.alertDialog=alertDialog;
    }
    public void run()
    {
         //do something with dialog
    }
```

In another thread:

```
public class UpdateMapRunnable implements Runnable {

    public UpdateMapRunnable(FullMapFragment fragment) {
        this.fragment = fragment;

    }

    private FullMapFragment fragment; //volatile?

    private final Handler uiHandler = new Handler();

    @Override
    public void run() {     
        uiHandler.post(new ShowAlertDialog (fragment.getAlertDialog()));            
    }
```

Is that ok? Do I have to add volatile modificator to those fields?

Comment: Have you read about [volatile keyword](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/atomic.html) ?

Comment: Yes. I know that java could take data from thread cache. volatile forces java to take data directly from the memory. Am I right?

Comment: There are a little more impact from volitile than just that. And volatile make jvm re-read only pointer, not entire object. So better watch /read "Java Memory Model" presentation by Sergey Kuksenko.

Answer (score 0):

You should **never modify UI components outside UI thread**. Because if you'll change Dialog's components in the working thread while it is being rendered in AWT EQ, you will get an error and volatile won't help. But if you just want dialog to be accessible in another thread to prepare it, and you *surely* will show it only after all modifications, just make it final, it will be enough. Again, volatile won't help, as it only **makes pointer volatile, not the entire object**. And if you need concurrent changes on Dialog's properties, you need to sync it's fields/methods. Type of sync will vary depending on access mode. If one thread writes and others only read, volatile is ok, if more than 1 writer, you'll need something more strict, like Atomic or synchronized.

So, you can:

1) /*for concurrent changes*/ create a data model, which you compute and change (which can be a long work) and then in UI thread you only modify UI components corresponding to model state (which is fast). Here you will need some synchronization.

2) /*for non-concurrent changes*/ send a runnable code to UI thread to do all the work (in case you need threading, but not for UI work) like that:

```
EventQueue.invokeLater( ()->{ /*your work here*/ } );
```

3) do both 1 and 2. Almost all cases finally come to this.

*If everything is written right* you will need synchronization only when where is more than 1 worker (non-ui) thread.

Comment: Could you please answer my question?

Comment: The answer is 'no', if it wasn't clear enough, sorry.

Comment: Could you explain why? I don't modify components outside of UI thread. I'm using handler.

Comment: You said 'I want to change few components in another thread', and posted a code with a lot of runnables, but they can be ran from any thread. If you will change Dialog's components in the working thread while it is being rendered in AWT EQ, you will get an error and volatile won't help. But if you just want dialog to be accessible in another thread to prepare it, and you *surely* will show it only after all modifications, just make it final, it will be enough. Again, volatile won't help, as it only makes pointer volatile, not the entire object.

Comment: And if you need concurrent changes on Dialog's properties, you need to sync it's fields/methods. Type of sync will vary depending on access mode. If one thread writes and other only reads, volatile is ok, if more than 1 writer, you need something more strict, like Atomic or synchronized.

Comment: It will be nice, if you add your comment to answer.

Comment: Also I forgot to add "android" tag to my quesion